# Probability bound for complex random variable

Tags: probability, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $Z=X+iY$ be complex random variable. Consider the following probability
$$\mathrm{Pr}\left( | Z|\geq \epsilon \right)$$
 I want to bound this in terms of the real and imaginary parts of $Z$, i.e. suppose that I have bounds for $\mathrm{Pr}\left( |X|\geq \epsilon \right)\leq C(\epsilon)$ and $\mathrm{Pr}\left( | Y|\geq \epsilon \right)\leq C'(\epsilon)$. For starters, 
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Pr}\left( | Z|\geq \epsilon \right)
&=\mathrm{Pr}\left( |X+iY|\geq \epsilon \right) \\
&= \mathrm{Pr}\left( \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\geq \epsilon \right)\\
&= \mathrm{Pr}\left( X^2+Y^2\geq \epsilon^2 \right)
\end{align}
How to proceed?
Context: I am trying to understand how to lift the standard Chernoff bound to complex random variables. (see also [in this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124422/chernoff-hoeffding-bound-for-complex-values)
)

Answer (score 1):

$P(|Z| \geq \epsilon) \leq P(|X|\geq \epsilon /2)+P(|Y|\geq \epsilon /2)$ because $|Z| \leq |X|+|Y|$.

[ The event $(|Z| \geq \epsilon) $ is contained in the union of the events $(|X| \geq \epsilon) $ and $(|Y| \geq \epsilon) $].

Comment: weird, but then in the link, the real-valued Chernoff bound is $2e^{-K\epsilon^2/2b^2}$ but replacing $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon / 2$, I have $2\times 2e^{-K(\epsilon/2)^2/2b^2}=4e^{-K \epsilon^2 / 8b^2}$  but they get $4e^{-K \epsilon^2 / 4b^2}$ what is going on there?